# Prove that grammar $S \to aSc | \epsilon | bBc$ ,$B \to bBc | \epsilon$ generates language $\{a^ib^jc^{i+j} | i,j \ge 0 \}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, proof-assistants

Prove that grammar $G$ with productions:

> $S \to aSc|\epsilon | bBc$
>
> $B\to bBc | \epsilon$

Generates language $ L = \{a^ib^jc^{(i+j)}$ | $i,j \ge 0 \} $

Step 1. Prove $L(G) \subseteq L$
.

We are inducting on the number of steps in derivation $S \xrightarrow i w$ where $i\ge 1$.

- Base case: For $i=1$ is trivial and word generated is $\epsilon \in L$
- Inductive Hypothesis: Suppose there's some $n$ such that for all derivations $S \xrightarrow n w$ , $n\ge 1$, a word $w$ is in $L$. So w derived is $a^ib^jc^{n-1}$, where $n=i+j+1$ and $i,j \ge 0$
- Inductive Step: Suppose we need $n+1$ steps to derive a word $w$. We can write $S \to aSc \xrightarrow n w$ or $S \to bBc \xrightarrow n w$.

Case 1 $S \to aSc \xrightarrow n w$: Let $w = axc$ such that $S\xrightarrow n x$. By Inductive Hypothesis $x=a^ib^jc^{(n-1)}$. So $w=aa^ib^jc^{n-1}c = a^{i+1}b^jc^{i+j+1-1+1} = a^{i+1}b^jc^{i+j+1}$ And indeed $w \in L$ since $i+j+j=i+j+1$

Case 2: ...

Is case 1 approached in the right way ? In my previous proofs I was able to write a word w in a way that it only had one variable n connected to the number of derivations, but here I also have i and j and not only n.

Comment: If your proof is valid, that you did it "the right way". More generally, in math we don't have "the right way". There is more than one way to prove a theorem. Any valid proof is right. Some methods might be simpler, and preferable for other reasons, but the main property against which a proof is measured is *correctness*.